# Passing a dictionary as an element to another dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dictionary

I have a requirement where I am running a for loop to incrementally load data from excel to a dictionary followed by passing this to another dictionary. I am using the following code for that:

```
var contr = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>();
contr.Add("Contributor" + (j + 1), contributor_dictionary);
item.Add(contributor_list + (j + 1), contr);
```

The dictionary "contr" has data in the format:

```
contributor:{
 name: abc,
 title: xyz }
```

When I am adding this to the item dictionary, it is giving the output as:

```
contributor_list1:{
  contributor1:{
   name: abc,
   title: xyz }

contributor_list2:{
  contributor2:{
   name: def,
   title: mno } and so on..
```

whereas i want it in the format:

```
contributor_list:{
  contributor1:{
   name: abc,
   title: xyz },

  contributor2:{
   name: def,
   title: mno }
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: No, you don't want that. Don't emebed indexes in variable names.

Comment: Hi @JohnWu . I didn't get your point

Comment: If the key difference is only an index number, then why work with a dictionary at all and not just a list? -- Also, why `Dictionary<string, object>`? Are you planning on holding something different than a "Contributor" structure?

Comment: Also also: what is `contributor_dictionary` and `item`? And did you mean `"contributor_list"` instead of just `contributor_list`? Or is `contributor_list` a string variable/constant? -- since you add `contr` to it, `item` would be a `Dictionary<?, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>>`... that seems wrong...

Comment: The format you save data depend on the way how you will use this data. You say nothing about how you going to use it. You need to use Dictionary only when you need access some specific contributor, but if you going to manipulate data as a collection, then use `List` instead of `Dictionary`

Comment: And please create a class or struct which represent your data - will save time and make life easy for you and your colleges.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation and this is how i handled it.
Since you know how the format of your data is, you can use a struct like this

```
public struct ExcellData
    {
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        public string Title{ get; set; }
    }
```

then you can now have a dictionary to hold each excel data like this

```
public class MyDictionary : List<ExcellData>
    {
        public void Add(string key, string Name, string Title)
        {
            ExcellData val = new ExcellData();
            val.Name= Name;
            val.Title= Title;
            this.Add(val);
        }
    }
```

then in your loop you can do this

```
var cellData= new MyDictionary();
cellData.Add();
```

assuming your excel data has multiple values on a single row then your code could look like this

```
 public struct ExcellCells
    {
        public string Someoption { get; set; }
        public string SomeOptionType { get; set; }
        public string[] cellList { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyDictionary : List<ExcellCells>
    {
        public void Add(string key, string option, string[] xcell)
        {
            ExcellCells val = new ExcellCells();
            val.SomeOptionType = key;
            val.Someoption = option;
            val.cellList = xcell;
            this.Add(val);
        }
    }
```

hope this helps

Comment: It's obviously better than OP approach, but instead of inheriting of List, I would just encapsulate it in dedicated type.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are adding contributor to the item dictionary every time you loop. First create your contr dictionary collection then add it to the item.
No need to add index in item dict key. 
simply write:
item.Add(contributor_list,contr);
item dictionary seems redundant if contributor_list is constant/fixed string, but if it changes then its Ok.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are receiving the data from Excel in the form of a dictionary then you need the following:

```
public class Contributor
{
    int ContributorID {get; set;}  // optional
    string name  {get; set;}
    string title  {get; set;}
}
```

Then unpack your Excel dictionary into the `Contributor` object and add that object to your dictionary if you need a key (which you are not using above).

If you don't need a key then just use a list of `Contributor`